# Android: Fragments+Always on Top Layout at Bottom of Screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I want to do the same `pagination and menu` in my Android as they did in their iPhone App (please check the image). There is a `pagination` and app menu at the bottom of screen and they are `always on top`. If some screen has more contents and scroll, the `pagination` and menu position is `fixed` at bottom no matter user is scrolling down or up.

While answering, please consider following specs of my android app design:

1. This app is being developed in Android 2.1 (API Level 7)
2. This is fragment based app. I've only one activity and a lot of fragments (actually, I made fragment for each page that comes under `pagination` and I am showing and hiding fragments on swipe)

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To use `fragment` in android under 3.x, you must use [support library](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html)

And to keep some layout at a specific position in your screen, just use the basic layout control on android such as `Linearlayout, RelativeLayout`, ...

Comment: I think fragment already supported in 2.1. Why I need to use support library?

Comment: Not all things you think is true. Fragment is introduced from android 3.0. In earlier version, you must use support library. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Oh I got it now, yeah surely I added the Support Library. Before this, I didnt know its name as "Support Library". Thanks for introducing me with its "real" name :D

Comment: But all "things" you understood from my question is not true as well because I didnt ask how to use fragments in Android 2.1 rather I asked about the "layout" I want to make and unfortunately 2nd part of your answer is not clear enough that how to achieve it ;)

Comment: LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout is very basic on Android. You can use the attributes of these layout controls to arrange your items. For example, if you want to keep the button always on top of an RelativeLayout, just set android:layout_alignParentTop="true". For more information, let read at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/) for your paging requirement.

```
And for bottom layout you can fix the bottom layout inside main layout.
```

**Note:** 
First refer the project and then try for bottom approach.

Comment: Have you tried the approach for pagination given in that project yourself or you just googled and post link here? Please tell me something you tried yourself because a lot of such "samples" dont mean actually what we try to look for and most of them are totally different than our requirement :)

Comment: Yes I have tried, have a look at the code and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved very easily. Define your content layout for the activity like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/all_common_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="Some common layout" />

</LinearLayout
```

>

and replace framelayout with the fragment, so that Textview (all_common_view) will remain common to all the fragments you use.